# TypeError in Nextjs app production: [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'n.content')]

Tags: next.js, deployment, safari, typeerror, production-environment

I don't have any problems in dev mode, but when I deploy my Nextjs app to production, the above error appears, but only in Safari incognito mode..

I asked ChatGPT, but didn't get anywhere. Also didn't find any questions/answers related to this specific issue.

Usually I know what to do when I encounter a TypeError, but I've never seen this before. This `n` object is not something I defined. I think this gets compiled into the app when next builds it for production.

Is it possible that during the build process something goes wrong? Maybe I'm missing some settings?

Here's the `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "frontend-public",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "npm": "use Yarn!"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "grc": "npx generate-react-cli",
    "component": "yarn grc component",
    "hook": "yarn grc component --type=hook",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint -- --dir src",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:ci": "jest --ci",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public",
    "serve-storybook": "serve storybook-static"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-postcss": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "14.2.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.51.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "@types/lodash.isequal": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/react": "18.0.9",
    "@types/react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.5",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.44.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.44.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.0.5",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.7",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.9.1",
    "generate-react-cli": "^8.0.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.2",
    "jest": "28.1.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "28.1.0",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.19",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.0",
    "sass": "^1.49.0",
    "serve": "13.0.2",
    "storybook-addon-next": "1.3.1",
    "storybook-addon-next-router": "^4.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "4.6.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@fotexnet/react-auth": "^2.2.8",
    "@fotexnet/react-request": "^2.4.2",
    "@fotexnet/ui": "^1.4.2",
    "@fotexnet/utils": "^0.0.0-development",
    "@googlemaps/react-wrapper": "^1.1.35",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.9.10",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.15",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.117",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.15",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.13",
    "@types/he": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/numeral": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/react-collapse": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/react-facebook-login": "^4.1.5",
    "@types/sanitize-html": "^2.9.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.5",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "gapi-script": "^1.2.0",
    "he": "^1.2.0",
    "ioredis": "^5.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "nanoid": "^4.0.0",
    "next": "^13.1.6",
    "next-auth": "^4.18.6",
    "next-cookies": "^2.0.3",
    "qs": "^6.11.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-barcode": "^1.4.6",
    "react-collapse": "^5.1.1",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-cookie-consent": "^8.0.1",
    "react-countdown-circle-timer": "^3.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-feather": "^2.0.10",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^3.1.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.40.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2",
    "react-scrolllock": "^5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.1",
    "react-zoom-pan-pinch": "^3.1.0",
    "sanitize-html": "^2.11.0",
    "sharp": "^0.32.1",
    "swiper": "^8.4.5",
    "utility-types": "^3.10.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "zod": "^3.20.0"
  }
}
```

Here's the `next.config.js`:

```js
const path = require('path');

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    NEXT_PUBLIC_MAINTENANCE_MODE: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAINTENANCE_MODE,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_MOBILE_BASE_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MOBILE_BASE_URL,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_PURCHASE_API_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PURCHASE_API_URL,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_MAX_TICKET_COUNT: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAX_TICKET_COUNT,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_MAX_CHARACTER: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MAX_CHARACTER,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_TOKEN_HEADERS: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TOKEN_HEADERS,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_LAST_MINUTE: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_LAST_MINUTE,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_API_KEY: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_API_KEY,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY,
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID,
    FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET: process.env.FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    REDIS_HOST: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    REDIS_PORT: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
    REDIRECT_URI: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
  },
  output: 'standalone',
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'styles')],
  },
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },

  images: {
    domains: ['localhost', 'google.com', 'placehold.co'],
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'http',
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: '10801',
        pathname: '/media/**',
      },
    ],
  },
  // transpilePackages: [],
  webpack: config => {
    config.plugins = config.plugins || [];
    config.optimization.providedExports = true;
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/assets'),
      '@clients': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/clients/index.ts'),
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components'),
      '@data': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/data'),
      '@features': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/features'),
      '@guards': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/type-guards'),
      '@hoc': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/hoc'),
      '@hooks': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/hooks'),
      '@interfaces': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/interfaces'),
      '@layouts': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/layouts'),
      '@lib': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/lib'),
      '@pages': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/pages'),
      '@providers': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/providers'),
      '@public': path.resolve(__dirname, './public'),
      '@reducers': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/reducers'),
      '@schemas': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/schemas'),
      '@themes': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/themes'),
      '@utils': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/utils'),
      '@const': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/const.ts'),
      '@setup': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/setup.ts'),
      '@cards': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components/Cards'),
      '@badges': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components/Badges'),
    };

    return config;
  },
};
```

Here's the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
      "@clients": ["src/clients/index.ts"],
      "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "@data/*": ["src/data/*"],
      "@features/*": ["src/features/*"],
      "@guards/*": ["src/guards/*"],
      "@hoc/*": ["src/hoc/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["src/hooks/*"],
      "@interfaces/*": ["src/interfaces/*"],
      "@layouts/*": ["src/layouts/*"],
      "@lib/*": ["src/lib/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
      "@providers/*": ["src/providers/*"],
      "@public/*": ["public/*"],
      "@reducers/*": ["src/reducers/*"],
      "@schemas/*": ["src/schemas/*"],
      "@themes/*": ["src/themes/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
      "@const": ["src/const.ts"],
      "@setup": ["src/setup.ts"],
      "@cards/*": ["src/components/Cards/*"],
      "@badges/*": ["src/components/Badges/*"]
    },
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "src", "stories", "typings", "templates"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".next", "__tests__", "__mocks__"]
}
```

Comment: Hi @kmp, did you found out how to fix it?

Comment: I did fix it, but I can't explain how. I was using 2 hooks in a component, both sent an async request to the server and I guess the second hook came back earlier (it is depending on the first) and that caused this issue. I added a fallback to avoid this and I didn't see the error ever since.

Comment: Thanks :) In our case it occurs that different version of different ios and safari version have a problem with regexp - as we have only one in our app, it was easy to find out which was wrong